# How to localize CPAN module and dependencies

Tags: perl, internationalization, cpan

I am trying to localize a CPAN module [MooX::Options](https://github.com/celogeek/MooX-Options/pull/38) using [Locale::TextDomain](https://metacpan.org/pod/Locale::TextDomain) after having read ["On the state of I18N in perl"](http://rassie.org/archives/247).

In the discussion in the pull request the question came up how to deal with messages not originating in the module itself, but in a dependency. In this specific case, when you specify an option on the command line which is not defined anywhere in the code, you'll get the warning:

> Unknown option: xyz

originating in the module [Getopt::Long](https://metacpan.org/pod/Getopt::Long), which in itself is not localized yet.

The question is how to deal with these. I see basically three strategies:

1. Ignore them, which I find dissatisfactory.
2. Try to someway or other *catch all the corner cases and messages* in the module I'm currently localizing (in this case `MooX::Options`), and this way working around the missing localization in the dependent modules. This option seems brittle, as I'd have to constantly adapt to changes in the base modules. Sometimes, it might by next to impossible to catch messages, as they're written to output streams directly by the modules (as is the case in this example).
3. Try to *localize the dependent modules themselves*. This option seems hard to achieve, as different projects might use different I18N tools and strategies themselves and the dependency graph might be huge.

All in all, I think this problem is more general and not that specific to perl and cpan modules. So, I'm interessted in your thoughts, strategies and approaches.

Comment: I've been thinking about how to do this for the cpan client. I don't have any answers though.

Answer (score 2):

I have rather [strong opionions](http://www.nu42.com/2013/04/translation-of-programming-terms-and.html) on the idea of translating computing terms, and most people disagree with my views, so take what I am saying with a grain of salt.

I do not understand the point of internationalizing a library for parsing command line options unless you want to further [ghettoize](https://www.google.com/search?q=ghettoize) what is already a small group of users of said library.

Would `wget` be more useful to Turkish users if instead it was called `wal` or `wgetir`? Or, instead of `wget --mirror`, should Turkish users write `getir --ayna`? What about that `w`?

If you just translate the messages, what is the point of outputting a help message in response to `wget -h` when the Turkish equivalent would be `wget -y`?

The fact is, almost all attempts at translating programming related terms I have seen are [simply awful](http://www.nu42.com/2014/08/replacing-hash-keys-with-values-does.html). The people who are most eager to translate are usually not in command of either human language — Nor do they seem to  understand what they are translating.

However, as a result of these eager people, I find that at least the Turkish translations of pretty much any software I touch is just awful. Whatever Danish translations I have seen did not fare much better, but, at least, they were tolerable owing to the greater commonality of structure between Danish and English.

I think everyone's energy is better spent on actually making sure their programs handle ***content***, including names of external resources/references, in different languages well, rather than giving me error messages in some Frankenstein language, or letting me specify command line options whose mnemonics do not match their descriptions etc, or presenting menus that contain of strings of words that really do not convey any meaning.

I have felt this way for the last for many decades now ... Even when I was patching IBM PC keyboard drivers with hex editors so people at various places could type reports in WordStar, and create charts in Harvard Graphics.

So, my unpopular advice is to put your energy elsewhere ...

For example, use exception objects so the user of your library (who is likely a programmer and will understand "Directory not found" much more readily than "Kütük bulunamadı") can deduce in a human-language independent way what happened, and what message to show the user. I haven't looked closely at `MooX::Options`, but I notice there is at least one string `croak`.

Here is an [actual error message from an IBM product](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_8.2.0/com.ibm.db2.udb.doc/core/r0ccamsg.htm?lang=tr):

> Belirtilen kütük örüntüsüyle eşleşen hiçbir kütük bulunamadı

You can ask every one of the almost 200 million Turkic people on earth what a "kütük örüntüsü" is, and only the person who actually came up with this non-sensical string of characters will be able to tell you that it corresponds to "file pattern". What, then, do they gain by using the phrase "kütük örüntüsü" versus "file pattern"? Nothing.

However, they lose the ability to communicate with, and, also, compete with, programmers in the English speaking world.

PS: Apologies for all Turkish examples, but I feel most comfortable drawing abominable examples based on my native language.

Comment: This does not answer the question at all

Comment: @ikegami The first item on the OP's list is: "1. Ignore them, which I find dissatisfactory." My answer makes the point that (1) is a valid option, but it requires some explanation of my motivation as translating into a bunch of different languages seems to be the unquestioned default these days.

Comment: Re "My answer makes the point that (1) is a valid option". No, it does not. It doesn't even touch the topic of not translating library messages. You talk about not translating computer terms, which is completely unrelated to the question.

Comment: @SinanÜnür Thank you for your answer! But I think ikegami is right. I was not proposing tranlating 'computer terms', or, for that matter, terms used in the user interface of the command. (The `cp` command takes the same command line options no matter what your locale is set to.) My concern is about documentation, help, and error strings.

Comment: @sschober If you are going to have the messages translated, they will most likely not be good translations (see the error message from the IBM product). And, I do not see the point of not translating `cp` ... After all, it is short for `copy` ... shouldn't it adapt to the user's language? Command line options are memorable because a single letter or short string corresponds to something that means something in English. And, "Unknown option" or "File not found" are computing terms as well.

Comment: The point of not translating commands and their options is that they're part of the interface of the command (think of scriptability). Making an interface locale dependent is not a very good idea in my opinion.

Comment: "Making an interface locale dependent is not a very good idea in my opinion." Neither is making it impossible for humans to transfer their knowledge of how programs work from one country to another. If the lack of consistency would hurt a machine, why not care as much about the human user? If a Turkish user wants to know what an error message means, she needs to figure out what it is in English and look it up. Why make it difficult for her? **What is the purpose of translating "Unknown option"?**